# why the same JS code is not working for the second post/image but works fine with first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/rhbwpn19/4/

Image preview is working  fine for the first post but not for the other posts.

what should I change here ?

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}
}



$("#imgInp").change(function() {
 readURL(this);
});
```

1.click on the dropdown menu and select View.

[image]

2. It will  preview the image. now browse any image from your computer and  it will immediately show

[image]

3. It works fine.

[image]

4. But not working for the second post/image .
   [image]

Comment: `img#blah` is only in the first modal. Also, you don't need a FileReader, use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead.

Comment: still not working after adding id="blah"  besides in my projects all have the id="blah"   but not working ...any solution ??

Comment: id must be unique in the document, use an other selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

1.In your HTML, You have two `#imgInp` elements.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document). - [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp)

Use two different ids for the two file inputs like below.

```
<input type="file" class="file" id="imgInp1"/>
<input type="file" class="file" id="imgInp2"/>
```

2.Use `.file` as the selector in your JS. (to select both inputs.)

```
$('.file').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

3.Check for the clicked input and handle them.

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    if($(input).attr('id')==='imgInp1') { // first input
        $('#blah1').attr('src', e.target.result);
    } else if ($(input).attr('id')==='imgInp2'){ // second input
        $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/rhbwpn19/10/

This is my first answer. Let me know if i have done anything wrong. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the id  `blah` for image preview and `imgInp` for input `file` in the other modal so below i put them for `blah2` and `imgInp2` but the other problem is when you upload on the 1st modal on first input it is showing also to 2nd modal. Sorry for bad english.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
$("#imgInp2").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');


.2nd-post{
  
  margin-top:50;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<div class="dropdown" style=" float:right; margin-right:28% ">
   
   <span style=" cursor: pointer; " class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   
  
   
   </span>
   
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a>View</a></li>
    
    
  </ul>
   
   
   
   </div>

<img  style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);margin-left: 8%;  " src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg" width=" 80%" />




<div class="dropdown" style=" float:right; margin-right:28% ">
   
   <span style=" cursor: pointer; " class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   
  
   
   </span>
   
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><a>View</a></li>
    
    
  </ul>
   
   
   
   </div>

<img  style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);margin-left: 8%;  " src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/EPUlp9X_YqNR99f.jpg" width=" 80%" />




<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        
        
        
        
  <div id="edit_post">

  
  
  
  
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:1%">
  
  
  </div>
   

  
   <input type="file" name="image2" class="file" id="imgInp"/>
  
  
   <img id="blah" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);margin-left: 8%;  " src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg" width=" 80%" />

   
   
  

  
  </div>
  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button  style="float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <span  >  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="saveedit" > Save </button></span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        
        
        
        
  <div id="edit_post">

  
  
  
  
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:1%">
  
  
  </div>
   

  
   <input type="file" name="image2" class="file" id="imgInp2"/>
  
  
   <img id="blah2" style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);margin-left: 8%;  " src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/EPUlp9X_YqNR99f.jpg" width=" 80%" />

   
   
  

  
  </div>
  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button  style="float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <span  >  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="saveedit" > Save </button></span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```